# Can I disconnect a light and leave wires capped on a live circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

In an apartment with 2 separate LED lights, so I can’t simply take bulb out. Hate one of the lights. Am I okay to disconnect one and leave the wires capped while still using the same circuit for the other light? And will just reconnect when I leave in a year.

Comment: If they're *separate* lights, what's stopping you from taking the bulb out?

Comment: doesn't sound dangerous as-described, and it would work, if it would be discovered it would just get flagged to fix, you wouldn't be "busted" by code enforcers, though your landlord might not be too happy.

Answer (score 3):

No. It's illegal for you to do wiring in an apartment unless you are a licensed electrician, at least in the USA. Your landlord can't either.

Has to do with the risk to all the other people in the building when your amateur electrical work starts a fire. Homeowners are assumed to have adequate self-interest to do their own electrical on single-family buildings in some areas - other areas, particularly densely populated ones with a history of fire issues don't even allow that.

Comment: For what it's worth: decades ago in the St Louis area, there was a program where homeowners could take an abbreviated version of the electrician's certification test to get permission to work as apprentice electricians on their own house. A fully certified electrician had to come in once or twice during a large project to confirm that everything was being done in accordance with code, and I think final connection to power required OK from the town inspector. Interesting compromise between "your house, your risk" and "yeah, but insurance and fire dept want to know it's safe".

Comment: One might suspect that apartment dwellers usually have a reasonable level of self-preservation as do individual home owners. However, if I, as a home owner, burn down my house due to shoddy workmanship, lack of knowledge, whatever, it's _my_ house. OTOH, if I, as an apartment dweller burn down the apartment building, it's also _your_ house and _her_ house and _their_ house, too.

Comment: Does the proscription apply to townhomes, duplexes, etc. as well?

Comment: @Huesmann "multiple dwelling units" is the code language (MDUs) so generally, yes.

Comment: @Huesmann -- duplexes, yes.  a fee simple townhome may still be eligible for a homeowner's exemption/certification though